# When to use factory patterns?

Tags: model-view-controller, .net-3.5, factory

What is this factory all about and what are the advantages of using factory patterns? Does it give a plugable architecture? Why it is called "Factory"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is factory since it is actually "Manufacturing" (Create) an object.

There's actually two kind of factory pattern defined by GoF:

1. [Factory Method](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx#_self1)
2. [Abstract Factory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAbstract.aspx)

Basically both of them tries to decouple the calling client from knowing the actual concrete implementation of the class/interface.

Comment: So this would be useful if you needed to account for the possibility that your model (in MVC) might change? Is there anything undesirable about creating a model in your application that is dynamic depending on the circumstances ? I'm guessing one downside is the added complexity of making sure that any permutations don't break your views or your controllers.

Answer (score 3):

You can find all you need by reading [this](http://www.patterndepot.com/put/8/factory.pdf)  PDF article

Comment: you should advice that this is a download link. (pdf)

Comment: Link now Broken :(

Comment: Cached google result is still available (for now) https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ptz7qhMKFD0J:https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse403/07sp/lectures/design2.pdf%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=nl