# Possible advantages of Factory Design Pattern over MVC?

Tags: design-patterns

I am planning to go through Factory Design pattern for a certain project. However, I am very new to it, just wanted to know if it's really worth trying to use Factory Pattern over MVC ? What are the possible advantages of using Factory D.P over MVC ?

Comment: advantage of one pattern over other is solely depend upon your project type and needs

Answer (score 6):

[MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is a Model-View-Controller - high-level architectural pattern which intend is separating UI from from model. [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28design_pattern%29) is a low-level pattern which intend is a creation of objects. How these patterns could be compared?

Comment: I agree with @lazyberezovsky. It is kind a strange to compare these to different patterns with different purpose. You can use both of them at the same time without breaking any architectural structure.

Comment: Had to google this exact thing just now as an interviewing candidate just said that MVC is superior to the factory pattern

Answer (score 1):

this question will help [When to use factory patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067271/when-to-use-factory-patterns)
to understand factory pattern & MVC better  [read this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/ora_as3_design_patterns.html)